# Unable to capture part of a line using sed -n '/.../p'

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed to store a string in a variable. I'd like to pick out part of one line in a text file, but am unable to do so.

For example, if a line of text from which I'd like to extract the text is:

`{foo bar 1.1.2} foo`

And I'd like to extract `bar 1.1.2`

My command looks like:
`BarVersion=$(sed -n "/bar [.0-9]/p" file.txt)`

However, if I then write:

`echo $BarVersion`

I find that the sed command has saved the whole line in BarVersion, not the just the part I was looknig for. i.e. I get `{foo bar 1.1.2} foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with grep like this:

```
BarVersion=$(grep -o "bar [.0-9]*" file.txt)
```

This seems to work for me, but of course it's not using sed, but in my opinion it's a bit simpler.

`-o` means only output the part of the line that matched.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo '{foo bar 1.1.2} foo' | sed -n 's/^.*\(bar [\.0-9]*\)}.*$/\1/p'
bar 1.1.2
```

- `s/x/y/` substitutes `x` with `y`
- `\(\)` forms a group which you can reference via `\1`
- `[\.0-9]*` is any number of dots `.` and digits
- `^` is the start of the buffer, `$` is the end
- `.*` is any number of characters

Comment: This will also print all the lines that don't match the pattern and have no substitution done on them. Not an issue when you just feed one line with `echo`, but a problem when processing `file.txt`.

Comment: My mistake. I always thought that the `p` at the end was unconditional, but it only prints if a substitution occurred.

Comment: Not quite, it only prints if the searched-for RE was matched. It doesn't matter whether or not a substitution also occurred when the RE was matched.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running GNU/something,

```
sed -nr '/^\{([^ ]*) ([^}]*)\} \1$/ s//\2/p'
```

If the matching 'foo's isn't a requirement it's

```
sed -n /^{[^ ]* \([^}]*\)} .*/ s//\1/p'
```